# How to change a string from a json file to a random string

Tags: java, android, json

I have json file that i need to change a word from this json and
i want to change string word to a random string 
before i do that i need to know how to write and read json file from android studio or intellij and after that what to write to change the string.

the json file look like this:

```
  {
      "Bath" : {
        "-KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd" : {
          "autor" : "test467",
          "locationBathALon" : -34.770635,
          "locationBathBLat" : 150.8112166,
          "messageNameBath" : "Park Road Reserve",
          "ratebath" : "4.0"
        },
        "-KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd" : {
          "addressBath" : "George Hanley Drive",
          "autor" : "test467",
          "locationBathALon" : -34.40937488,
          "locationBathBLat" : 150.89999737,
          "messageNameBath" : "The Lagoon Seafood Restaurant",
          "ratebath" : "4.0"
        },
        "-KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd" : {
          "autor" : "test467",
          "locationBathALon" : -34.42711139,
          "locationBathBLat" : 150.89886635,
          "messageNameBath" : "Wollongong City Council and Library",
          "ratebath" : "4.0"
            }
      }
    }
```

I want to change the string "KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd" to a random string that for everyone be a other string.
i prefer to do that with some software that do that. If software like this not exist, what i need to write to do that in java or android? I'll be happy for some example code

Comment: What output do you want? It looks like you already have random keys for your data.

Comment: Yep, looks pretty random already.

Comment: You'd better post fake data to demonstrate the idea, corporate policy can bite you know.

Comment: i dont need fake data! i need to change the father word -KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd to a random word each one!

Comment: is it random string reversible or not?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

Generate random String

```
public String randomString(int len){
        final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-!@#$%&*";
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( len );
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            sb.append( AB.charAt( rnd.nextInt(AB.length()) ) );
        return sb.toString();
    }


String json = json.replace("-KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd",randomString("-KNYTXnET3oJPOCG64fd".length()));
```

Comment: i guess that what i need but the problem is how can i read and write to the json file if you can write it in a code like you did its be the best

Comment: Is this what you mean? [Read and Write Json](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: yes, but i try this before and its not working for me